# select multiple rows with condition for one row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot-table, crosstab

I am trying to join 2 tables, events and event_dates, each event has many dates

events table contains `ID`, `name`; event_dates - `ID`, `event_id`, `date`, `place_id` every day is one line in `event_dates` table. For different days `place_id` can be different.

I want to show the list of the events for this month - but only those, that for today have place_id = 1.

What sql query should I write for that ?
Thanks

**edit**

I apologize, I missed smth, the in result along with events I have to show the `event_dates` table for each event.

so the result will be like

```
1) event id and name with its dates for this month (and for today place_id = 1)
2) other event id and name  with its dates for this month (and for today place_id = 1)
etc

SELECT e.*, d.date
FROM events e
JOIN event_dates d
ON e.id = d.event_id
WHERE d.date BETWEEN {d '2013-08-01'} and {d '2013-08-31'}
AND d.place_id = 1
```

this query does not work, because, what if for all the month the place_id is 2, 3 or smth else, and only for today 1 in that case I will have only events with only todays rows from event_dates table

**RESULT should be as follows**

```
                Aug1        Aug2        Aug3 ....   Aug21(today)    . . .Aug30
eventName1      placeId     placeId     placeId      placeId            placeId
eventName2      placeId     placeId     placeId     placeId             placeId
eventName3      placeId     placeId     placeId     placeId             placeId
```

So, am showing the list of the evens with their information for this month, but all this events that are listed should have placeId = 1 for today.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  While I could just write out a query that would solve this issue for you, it really feels like you've tried nothing as the query I would write is one of the more basic INNER JOIN queries.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net, apologize, I missed to mention the most important condition, without that it was just simple join, u were right

Comment: @John: I don't understand. You've written: I want to show the list of the events for this month - but only those, that for today have place_id = 1. If i your month you have all places different by 1, for me, you haven't rows. Please add some samples as you want your result.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT e.*, d.date
FROM events e
JOIN event_dates d
ON e.id = d.event_id
WHERE d.date BETWEEN {d '2013-08-01'} and {d '2013-08-31'}
AND d.place_id = 1
```

But I have a doubt. If you have more days with place_id = 1 you want to show your event more times?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *.events from events 
left join event_date 
on id.events = event_dates.event_id 
where event_dates.dates between '01/08/2013' AND '31/08/2013' 
AND event_dates.place_id = 1;
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN is more expensive of INNER JOIN (you have simulated an INNER because in WHERE clause you have put a condition of slave table event_dates)

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT events.id, events.name,event_dates.date,event_dates.place_id
FROM events
INNER JOIN event_dates
ON events.id=event_dates.event_id
WHERE event_dates.date = sysdate and event_dates.place_id=1;
```